# actionscript-3: check if movieClip exists

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieclip created with the following code:

```
var thumbContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
thumbContainer.name = "thumbContainer";
stage.addChild (thumbContainer);
```

If the window gets larger/smaller I want everything back in place. So I have an stage Event Listener. Now I want to see if this mc exists to put back in place. I've tried different ways but keep getting an error that does not exist.

**1120: Access of undefined property thumbContainer.**

```
if (this.getChildByName("thumbContainer") != null) {
 trace("exists")
}
```

and

```
if ("thumbContainer" in this) {
 trace("exists")
}
```

or

```
function hasClipInIt (mc: MovieClip):Boolean {
 return mc != null && contains(mc);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
stage.addChild (thumbContainer);
//...
if (this.getChildByName("thumbContainer") != null)
```

You are adding the `thumbContainer` to `stage` and checking for its existence with `this`. Change `stage` to `this` or `this` to `stage`.

That said, an even more appropriate way is to keep a reference to the added movie clip and check for existence with the [contains](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains()) method. It determines whether the specified display object is a child of the `DisplayObjectContainer` instance or the instance itself. The search includes the entire display list including this `DisplayObjectContainer` instance, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so on.

Hence you can easily check using `stage.contains(thumbContainer);`

Comment: Well my check works, so I can check if the mc exists, but now I want to do something with it. This (instance name) wont work:

var thumbContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
thumbContainer.name = "test";
thumbContainer.x = 10;
stage.addChild (thumbContainer);
if (this.getChildByName("test") == null) {
 trace ("something"); //Works!
 this.getChildByName("test").x = 10; //Works not!
 stage.test.x = 10; //Works not!
}

Answer (score 2):

if you are having trouble firing errors, you can always resort to a try catch

```
try{
  /// do something that will blow up...
}catch( e:Error ){
  trace( "we had an error but its not fatal now..." );
}
```

Comment: After a lot of research, only this solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that 'stage' and 'this' are not the same...that's why I couldn't talk to the mc.
this works:

```
var thumbContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
thumbContainer.name = "thumbContainer";
addChild (thumbContainer);
if (getChildByName("thumbContainer") != null) {
    trace("exists")
}
```

Comment: you should mark Amarghosh as correct answer, since your solution is based on his answer. It is o.k. to post the full solution to show how you solved the initial described problem. But it is not usual, that you mark yourself as author of the answer, as it is actually based on another answer, which helped you find your solution. so without, you would have been stuck. So credit the original author, even though he did not deliver the exact lines that you needed - which obviously is not possible, since none of us have your full code.